# Ошибка при миграции ASP.NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" либо одну из их зависимостей. Файл или папка повреждены. Чтение невозможно. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80070570)

Использую Visual Studio 2019. Пробовал переустанавливать ничего не помогло. Версия ASP.NET Core 2.1

Comment: Укажите версию .NET Core

Comment: @Arantler указал

Comment: эта сборка из полного .NET FW, зачем вам она нужна в вашем приложении?

Comment: @Konst так дело в том что я ее нигде не использую, когда пробую сделать Add-Migration выскакивает эта ошибка